# How can I make this code run faster?

Tags: java, drawing

I have created a graphing program that takes a user inputted y or x intercept form equation and graphs the matching line on the grid. It works, but it is incredibly slow to graph the lines. It was fast before I added the code where it uses the user's input, so I know it is some inefficiency with that part. I would really appreciate if anyone would take a little time to look through my code and give me some suggestions/tips on how I can make it run faster.

This is the code for the main Frame class:

```
package src;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

/*
 * This class is responsible for making the program's frame
 */

public class MainFrame 
{
    public static int width = 1001;
    public static int height = 1001;
    public static String equation;
    public static boolean drawLine = false;
    //public static String equation;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        EquationConverter ec = new EquationConverter();

        //These are the JPanels that put together the window
        JPanel northPane = new JPanel();
        JPanel southPane = new JPanel();
        JPanel eastPane = new JPanel();
        JPanel westPane = new JPanel();

        Color panelColor = new Color(230, 230, 230);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        //JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

        //Set the window's layout
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Create the grid panel
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        JPanel graphPane = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                setBackground(Color.white);
                g2.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

                int x1 = 0;
                int y1 = 0;
                int x2 = 0;
                int y2 = height;

                //Draw horizontal lines
                for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
                {
                    g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                    x1 += width/20;
                    x2 = x1;
                }
                g2.drawLine(width-1, 0, width-1, height);

                x1 = 0;
                y1 = 0;
                x2 = width;
                y2 = 0;

                //Draw vertical lines
                for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
                {
                    g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                    y1 += height/20;
                    y2 = y1;
                }
                g2.drawLine(0, height-1, width, height-1);

                //Make the x and y axis lines bigger and
                //a darker color than the grid lines
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
                g2.setColor(Color.black);
                g2.drawLine(500, 0, 500, 1001);
                g2.drawLine(0, 500, 1001, 500);

                //Draw numbers along y axis
                g2.setFont(new Font("defualt", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                int sx = 475;
                int sy = 60;
                String si;
                for (int i = 9; i >= -9; i--)
                {
                    if (i != 0)
                    {
                        si = Integer.toString(i);
                        g2.drawString(si, sx, sy);
                    }
                    sy += 50;
                }

                sx = 40;
                sy = 525;
                //Draw numbers along the x axis
                for (int i = -9; i <= 9; i++)
                {
                    if (i != 0)
                    {
                        si = Integer.toString(i);
                        g2.drawString(si, sx, sy);
                    }
                    sx += 50;
                }

                if (drawLine == true)
                {
                    double x = 0;
                    double y = 0;
                    String newEquation = "";
                    String finalEquation = "";
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
                    g2.setColor(Color.red);

                    equation = textField.getText();
                    equation = equation.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
                    if (!equation.equals(""))
                    {
                        if (equation.charAt(0) == 'y' && equation.charAt(1) == '=')
                        {   
                            equation = equation.substring(2);
                            newEquation = ec.editStr(equation, 'x');


                            //Draws lines using y intercept form
                            for (x = -10; x < 10; x+=0.0001)
                            {
                                //y = (x);
                                finalEquation = ec.replaceX(newEquation, df.format(x), 'x');
                                y = Double.parseDouble(ec.solveEquation(finalEquation));
                                g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(width/2+50*x, height/2-50*y,
                                            width/2+50*x, height/2-50*y));
                            }
                        }
                        else if (equation.charAt(0) == 'x' && equation.charAt(1) == '=')
                        {
                            equation = equation.substring(2);
                            newEquation = ec.editStr(equation, 'y');

                            //Draws lines using x intercept form
                            for (y = -10; y < 10; y+=0.0001)
                            {
                                //x = (y);
                                finalEquation = ec.replaceX(newEquation, df.format(y), 'y');
                                x = Double.parseDouble(ec.solveEquation(finalEquation));
                                g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(width/2+50*x, height/2-50*y,
                                            width/2+50*x, height/2-50*y));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    drawLine = false;
                }
            }
        };


        //Settings for the graph panel
        frame.add(graphPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            graphPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));


        //Settings for the north panel
        frame.add(northPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            northPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500, 30));
            northPane.setBackground(panelColor);


        //Settings for the south panel
        southPane.add(textField);
            textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 80));
            textField.setFont(new Font("default", Font.PLAIN, 60));
            textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    drawLine = true;
                    graphPane.repaint();
                }
            });


        //Settings for the east panel
        frame.add(eastPane, BorderLayout.EAST);
            westPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(247, 1500));
                westPane.setBackground(panelColor);


        //Settings for the west panel
        frame.add(westPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
            eastPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(247, 1500));
            eastPane.setBackground(panelColor);


        //Settings for the frame
        frame.setTitle("Custom Graphs");
        frame.setSize(1501, 1501);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the class that contains methods for converting the user's equation into a string that the computer can use to graph the line:

```
package src;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

/*
 * This class converts the user's equation for use by the computer
 */

public class EquationConverter
{
    //This method adds multiplication signs at necessary points in the sting
    protected String editStr(String str, char xOrY)
    {
        String newStr = str;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            //Adds a multiplicative sign between variables and digits
            if (i != 0 && str.charAt(i) == xOrY && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i-1)))
            {
                    newStr = str.substring(0, i) + "*" + str.substring(i);
            }
            //Adds a multiplicative sign between parentheses
            else if (i != 0 && str.charAt(i) == '(' && str.charAt(i-1) == ')')
            {
                newStr = str.substring(0, i) + "*" + str.substring(i);
            }
            str = newStr;
        }
        return newStr;
    }

    //This method replaces the character x with the numeric value of x
    protected String replaceX(String str, String number, char xOrY)
    {
        String newStr = str;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && str.charAt(i) == xOrY)
            {
                if (str.length() == 1)
                {
                    newStr = number;
                }
                else
                {
                    newStr = number + str.substring(i+1);
                }
            }
            else if (i != 0 && str.charAt(i) == xOrY)
            {
                //Add parentheses where there could be two minus signs
                if (i+1 == str.length())
                {
                    newStr = str.substring(0, i) + "(" + number + ")";
                }
                else
                {
                    newStr = str.substring(0, i) + "(" + number + ")" + str.substring(i+1);
                }
            }
            str = newStr;
        }
        return newStr;
    }

    //This method solves a string equation and returns the numeric value
    protected String solveEquation(String str)
    {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("javascript");
        try
        {
            return engine.eval(str).toString();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.exit(0);
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `setPreferredSize`, as general rule, but especially, don't do it in the `paintComponent` method; Don't call `setBackground` in the `paintComponent` method

Comment: So I should do `setBackground` outside the `paintComponent`? And what should I use instead of `setPreferredSize`?

Comment: `iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), enter);` ... really? You couldn't attach an `ActionListener` to the text fields? `DrawingThreads` scares me

Comment: Hm, I must of left `DrawingThreads` in by accident. I was experimenting with another class but it wasn't suppose to be there.

Comment: *"And what should I use instead of setPreferredSize?"* - Override `getPreferredSize` instead; *"So I should do setBackground outside the paintComponent?"* - Yes.  Calling these is trigger a new paint request which is probably where a good portion of your trouble is coming from

Comment: Have you tried a profiler to find out where the time is spent? If so, what did it show?

Comment: Depending on how often you intend to update the graph, you could render it to a backing buffer (like a `BufferedImage`) and render that through the `paintComponent` method, rather than having `paintComponent` do it EVERY time it's called

Comment: Try to avoid doing anything complex in `paint` methods - you have little control over how often it is called. Much better is to have a `BufferedImage` that is drawn once each time it needs to change and then have `paintComponent` use `drawImage`.

Comment: Yeah, because at one point, every time I minimized the frame, when I opened it up again, the whole screen was black.

Comment: I don't know how to use a profiler @sprinter

Comment: If you're using a modern IDE (eclipse, netbeans etc.) then it's pretty trivial as they have profilers built in or as an easily installable plug-in. I suggest reading the documentation of your IDE on how to profile your code.

Comment: I use Eclipse, but I haven't looked around and found the profiler yet. I will have to look into that.

Comment: I certainly suggest you get used to profiling your code: it's notoriously difficult to improve performance by code inspection.

Comment: It will make your code run faster if `paintComponent` is called multiple times (which it almost certainly is). Start with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/